# Omniauth - Display facebook connect as popup

Tags: facebook, omniauth

I am using Omniauth and forcing /auth/facebook to display in a popup (with JS).
[Instead of a new window - which is much less user friendly]

The problem is: Omniauth loads the FB url with

```
display=page
```

Instead of what I want:

```
display=popup
```

Anyone knows how I can change the params Omniauth uses for facebook ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At where you set your Facebook ID and secret key, add one more extra option as:

```
:display => "popup"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me using Omniauth 0.2.6 in a rails 3.1.0.rc5 app. Is there anything else I might need to do?

Comment: Can you guide me where exactly I need to put this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in the current version of omniauth-facebook, this is what works for me:

```
:authorize_params => { :display => 'popup' }
```

Comment: Here is [a relevant github issue for the omniauth-facebook project](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/5).  I'm not sure why it's closed because the `:authorize_params` for is undocumented.  I've asked to have it reopened.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using heroku, then use this option:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_APP_SECRET'], {:scope => 'email, offline_access', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'}}, :display => 'popup' }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this with Devise, simply edit your development.rb (and production.rb) to the following;

```
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_API, FACEBOOK_SECRET, :display => 'popup'
```

Make sure you restart your rails server upon editing these files.