# Is it possible to use FB Connect in an iframe on a 3rd party site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, iframe, omniauth

I have an iframe on a 3rd party site. Inside the iframe is my application, which users authenticate to using FB Connect. I am using the omniauth gem with my Ruby on Rails site to handle the connection to Facebook.

It works seamlessly if a) you are already logged in to FB, and b) you have already given my site permission to use your details.

If either of these are missing - at that moment where FB connect calls out to Facebook - it all stops, and I get the FB logo and a link to click through to Facebook. When I click the link - it takes me out of my iframe and into Facebook. Obviously once I return - there is no iframe to go back to and I am no longer on the 3rd party site - but on mine.

Should this technique be possible? And if so - where might I be going wrong? As I said - if a) and b) are met - it works seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the redirect to Facebook from within an iframe, it has to be loaded into the top-level page. That's why you see the FB logo and link, it's there to force a breakout of the iframe structure. If you want to avoid that intermediate step, make sure you do a top-level redirect yourself (usually by outputting some javascript code that sets top.location).

On the return side, you can either set redirect_uri to point to the 3rd-party site instead of directly to your site (or accepting the default redirect_uri which is probably doing that invisibly), or if that is impossible because of your app config on Facebook, detect that your page is being loaded into the top level and do a redirect to the 3rd-party site to force it back into the iframe.

Comment: Oh no - such a pity. I have seen the use of pop-ups on some sites. Would that work? So inside the iframe I open a popup on the main window - do the facebook connect process, and then close the popup. I don't think there would be a way to inform my site in the iframe that the authentication has completed. So - not sure if this is technically possible - my site in the iframe could poll for the authenticated cookie to 'arrive'?

Comment: It would be a rather strange flow, but it would be theoretically possible to open a new window which loads the Facebook auth page and then receives the redirect back to a page in your domain. That page could then output some javascript which communicated with the iframe using window.opener. But, wouldn't it be easier to do a top-level redirect and then jump back into the frame when done?

Comment: I found this: It looks like http://svpply.com/login is doing something like that. So if I add that url to an iframe - it works the way I want it to work. I am just not sure how they implemented it. I can see there is server side and client side ways to connect. After logging in they create a username - so it looks like there is some server side implementation as well. But yeah - I just don't know what the different steps are that they have taken.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup) - which helped me answer the question, using the technique of a popup.