# OmniAuth Facebook as Popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I'm trying to follow along with this solution for displaying Facebook as a popup with omniauth:

[Turn omniauth facebook login into a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup)

However the Answer states:

And then in your callback view:

```
:javascript
   if(window.opener) {
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close()
 }
```

I have followed the railscast for simple omniauth. I'm only using facebook. I have set :display=>popup in my initializer. However, I don't have a callback view, only a session controller and a create action. How can I use a view for the callback so I can put this code in?

Answer (score 1):

In your **routes.rb** file you must have specified callback with OmniAuth like this:

```
match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "Users#share"
```

Where You can have your action/method back in your **UsersController** class :

```
def share
 #Action you with to perform here!
end
```

and create its view file in **views** -> **users** -> **share.html.erb**

And you may have a different layout for this template if, you prefer to use one.