# Facebook Authentication prompts “Install” instead of “Log in with Facebook”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm currently facing this problem with ruby on rails 3, devise and facebook oauth.

When I click the button that connects me using facebook, I want the accept button in the prompt to say **Log In with Facebook** instead of **Install**.

This is located in my devise.rb file:

```
require 'omniauth-facebook'
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET
```

In my facebook app settings, I can see a bunch of options for configuring the auth dialog, but I see none regarding that button. I'm starting to think I created the wrong type of app. Perhaps it isn't an app I should have created but some sort of website connection? But I don't know where I can create that in www.developers.facebook.com. This should be fairly easy but googling yielded me nothing.

Comment: [This post is a little old but it describes the process of setting up `omniauth` and `devise` together in rails](http://www.railsatwork.com/2010/10/implementing-oauth-provider-part-1.html).  Check it out, could help you address your problem.  I have a feeling that you're not supposed to put the `omniauth` configuration statements inside of `devise.rb`, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I've tested it thoroughly and using current versions, you don't need an omniauth.rb file in your initializers. Now you use separate gems and require and configure them like that in the devise.rb file. Here's the documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

As a side note, the login function is working, I just want to change what the button says because it's misleading!

Comment: Hmm... I'm actually seeing this too now.  I'm not using `devise` so I don't think it has anything to do with devise.  Up until a few days ago it didn't prompt me to install, it asked if I wanted to login.  So perhaps this is a new thing with facebook.  Actually just went to my facebook app configuration and previewed my login dialog and it looks as though that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing and searching, I found out the answer although I don't like it much. With this:

```
# devise.rb
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, :display => 'popup'
```

The prompt now says **Log In with Facebook** instead of **Install**. The problem is that with this `:display => 'popup'` parameter, the page displayed by Facebook is really formatted to be used as a popup instead of a redirected page (so there is lot of white space). I guess I'll have to dig in a little to figure out how make it a real popup.

EDIT: To turn the page into a popup, check out Chris Heald's answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup/9592204).