# can't authenticate with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth

I'm following Ryan Bate's instructions for using Omniauth to set up third party authentication, except that I'm trying it with Facebook rather than Twitter, which he sets up in RailsCast 235.

After installing omniauth-facebook gem, and setting up the initializer

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'

end
```

I should be able to go to localhost:3000/auth/facebook and be presented with the Facebook login (even though it won't eventually work because we haven't set up the callback url yet) However, when i go to that url, I get this error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

and the url actually changes to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Coffline_access
```

On my app, I've set up Devise and followed the instructions on the Devise wiki for integrating Facebook authorization https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

Doing a Google search on the error message revealed that quite a few people have experienced this problem in recent weeks but couldn't find anyone with a solution
[image]

Comment: downvote without comment? childish

Comment: +1 Offsetting down vote, seems legit to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched for 101 and I stumbled upon [this page](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes). As you can see, that error stands for **Invalid API key**, so I believe that the problem lies in where you defined your key.

You should set up your key and your secret in a separate file (for clarity and security) but be mindful that Rails loads files in **alphabetical** order so the file that defines those constants should have a name that comes **before** the file that configures the oauth connection. In my case, I created a file called `constants.rb`, which comes before `devise.rb`. Also, make sure to keep this file away from source control. You don't want other people to have your keys and secrets.

```
# config/initializers/constants.rb
FACEBOOK_KEY = 'string'
FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'string'
```

Then configure your connection in your devise file if you are using devise or in your omniauth file if you are using simple omniauth:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb|omniauth.rb
require 'omniauth-facebook'
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET
```

Now, there is a better way to do this using ENV variables. I recommend the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#readme) as it really simplifies configuring apps.

If you want to display the facebook dialog page as a popup, you'll want to use

```
config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, :display => 'popup'
```

And follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup) later down the road.

And, if you are on Windows, you'll need a certificate so that the SSL connection does not fail. The solution to this problem is clarified by Arcolye [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720484/how-to-solve-certificate-verify-failed-on-windows).

Finally, to test your login locally, all you need to do is define your Site URL as `http://localhost:3000/`. That's all there is. You do *not* have to define your canvas URL.

Comment: strangely, i got the same error with your solution but when I moved the authentication numbers for Facebook_key and facebook_secret directly into config/initializers/devise.rb (i.e. didn't use the constants in the constants file) then it worked...

Comment: Were you using an ENV variable?

Comment: before you answered I was using environment variables in the terminal (and I also tested environment variables on heroku without success). then after you replied I put the actual keys into the constants file as you suggested. it didn't work, but then when I put the keys into devise.rb it worked...I'm going to go back and investigate more later tonight hopefully but I think that's what happened. At least we're close to a solution :)

Comment: @Ashitaka best bit of advice in your answer is the rails loading of files in alphabetical order, you have just saved some serious heartache :) thank you

Answer (score 3):

In the past, I had an issue using localhost with Facebook applications.  What I ended up doing was to create an entry in my host file on my computer to point fbdev.com to localhost and just used "fbdev.com" in place of localhost in the app settings on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error but I had forgotten to restart the server after adding my APP_ID and APP_SECRET :-P
Maybe that will help?

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have the following in `routes.rb`:

```
# Auth callback routes
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create' # This route is hit when a user gives the app permissions (the auth hash will be in request.env['omniauth.auth'])
match '/auth/failure' => 'sessions#failure' # This route is hit when a user doesn't give the app permissions
```

Second, ensure you have the following in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', :scope => 'email', :display => 'page'
end
```

Third, ensure you have `http://localhost:3000/` set as your **Canvas URL** in your Facebook app settings (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

[image]

You should then be able to simply redirect your users to `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook` to display the authentication dialog to them.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I use the omniauth-facebook gem for my app and it works as advertised. After searching, it seems the only possible case is that either your `APP_ID` or `APP_SECRET` is wrong. Double check these values.

Comment: do you have a public project on github with it setup?

Comment: No, it's a private repo. Sorry.

Comment: no problem. is it localhost:3000/auth/facebook/ that I'm supposed to be going to?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer to include my routes and initializer code. If they don't work for you, I'm not sure. Either your `app_id` or `app_secret` are wrong, your application is in sandbox mode, or some obscure Facebook field needs to be changed.

Comment: I'm getting a new error when I go to localhost:3000/auth/facebook/ . Updated OP. Not sure if this is progress or not. I haven't changed anything so don't know why error is changing.