# Rails 3: Popup option in Omniauth Facebook Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

This option is confusing me, as I mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/47)!

Is it supposed to actually deal with a popup window or does it mean something else? Just a bit strange as you get so much out of the box with Omniauth, yet this interaction is clunky.

I've seen this "solution" which isn't very elegant.

[Turn omniauth facebook login into a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup)

Am I missing something or do I need to ditch the server interaction and auth via the FB Javascript API?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

In short: "The display=popup option simply tells Facebook to provide a page optimized for display in a popup. You need to open the pop window yourself, using Javascript."

The smoothest UX seems to be using the FB JS API.

See:

https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/47#issuecomment-5524582