# How to shrink the omniauth FB dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

In my omniauth initializer file I have these settings:

```
provider :facebook, 'a_key', 'another_key',
     :scope => 'email', :display => 'popup'
```

But when the fb authentication dialog occurs, the login window is still full screen. I thought that the popup option would shrink the window. Is there another setting I need to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey just check carefully how the page is displayed when the  **:display => 'popup'**
attribute is present and then remove that and again check how the page is displayed. 
Check the difference between the views. 
**:display => popup** changes the view so that it can be shown in popup.

In order to shrink the window refer this answer [Turn omniauth facebook login into a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup)