# Popup window for Twitter login

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I'm trying to implement a pop-up window for my RoR project for the login functionality for Twitter. Currently, when you hit login, you are redirected to the authorization page, and then once you've logged in, you're redirected back. I want a pop-up window to come on top of the current browser window and then close after authentication.

This is my sessions controller:

```
def create
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
@user = User.find_by_user_id(auth_hash["uid"])
if @user
    @authorization = @user.authorization
    flash.now[:notice] = "Welcome back #{@user.name}! You have already signed up."
  session[:user_id] = auth_hash["uid"].to_i 
else
    @user = User.new :name => auth_hash["info"]["name"], :user_name => auth_hash["info"]["nickname"], :user_id => auth_hash["uid"], :profile_image_url => auth_hash["info"]["image"].sub("_normal", "")
  @user.build_authorization :secret => auth_hash['credentials']['secret'], :token => auth_hash['credentials']['token']
  @user.build_preference 
    @user.save!
    @user.errors.each do |error|
        puts error
end
    flash.now[:notice] = "Hi #{@user.name}! You've signed up."
  session[:user_id] = auth_hash["uid"].to_i
end
  redirect_to :root
end

def logout
session[:user_id] = nil
redirect_to :root
end

def failure
render :text => "Sorry, but you didn't allow access to our app!"
 end

 def destroy
@user = current_user
if @user
    @user.destroy
    end
redirect_to :root
   end

 end
```

I searched around and I see that a Javascript pop-up is the way to do it, so I got this from one of the other StackOverflow questions:

[Turn omniauth facebook login into a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491433/turn-omniauth-facebook-login-into-a-popup)

Where the code for the pop up is as below:

```
    function popupCenter(url, width, height, name) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    vartop = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
    return window.open(url, name, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",toolbar=no,left="+left+",top="+top);
    }

    $("a.popup").click(function(e) {
    popupCenter($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("data-width"), $(this).attr("data-height"), "authPopup");
    e.stopPropagation(); return false;
    });
```

And I've done the callback view, but what I don't know is where to put this line:

```
     =link_to "Log in with Facebook", omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook), :class => "popup", :"data-width" => 600, :"data-height" => 400
```

The class => popup line is supposed to go where we set the Twitter key/secret key, but I don't think that is the right location ([Omniauth - Display facebook connect as popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483598/omniauth-display-facebook-connect-as-popup)). It didn't work regardless. :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ?

Application Helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_login_with(provider, url, html_options = {})
    add_default_class(html_options)
    convert_popup_attributes(html_options)

    link_to t('.login_with_link', provider: provider), url, html_options
  end

  private

  def add_default_class(html_options)
    default_class = "js-popup"

    if html_options.has_key?(:class)
      html_options[:class] << " " << default_class
    else
      html_options[:class] = default_class
    end
  end

  def convert_popup_attributes(html_options)
    width = html_options.delete(:width)
    height = html_options.delete(:height)

    if width && height
      html_options[:data] ||= {}
      html_options[:data].merge!({width: width, height: height})
    end
  end
end
```

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Omniauth Popup</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <header class='main'>
    <nav class='user-nav'>
      <ul>
        <% if current_user %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to current_user do %>
              <%= image_tag current_user.image, class: 'user-pic' if current_user.image %>
              <%= content_tag :span, current_user.name %>
            <% end %>
          </li>
          <li><%= link_to t('.logout_link'), sign_out_path %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to_login_with 'Facebook', '/auth/facebook', { width: '460', height: '460' } %></li>
          <li><%= link_to_login_with 'GitHub', '/auth/github', { width: '1050', height: '700' } %></li>
          <li><%= link_to_login_with 'Google', '/auth/google', { width: '800', height: '470' } %></li>
          <li><%= link_to_login_with 'Twitter', "/auth/twitter?lang=#{I18n.locale}", { width: '660', height: '710' } %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id='js-messages' class='messages'>
    <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
      <span class='message <%= type %>'>
        <%= message %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class='content'>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app/assets/javascripts/login.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-popup').click(function() {
        centerPopup($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('data-width'), $(this).attr('data-height'));
        return false;
    });
});

function centerPopup(linkUrl, width, height) {
    var sep = (linkUrl.indexOf('?') !== -1) ? '&' : '?',
        url = linkUrl + sep + 'popup=true',
        left = (screen.width - width) / 2 - 16,
        top = (screen.height - height) / 2 - 50,
        windowFeatures = 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=' + width +
            ',height=' + height + ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top;
    return window.open(url, 'authPopup', windowFeatures);
}
```

Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Have a look at the info returned by the provider by uncommenting the next line:
    # render text: "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
    omniauth = env['omniauth.auth']
    user = User.find_or_create_with_omniauth(omniauth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    flash[:notice] = t('controllers.sessions.create', provider: pretty_name(omniauth.provider))
    render_or_redirect
  end

  def failure
    flash[:alert] = t('controllers.sessions.failure', provider: pretty_name(env['omniauth.error.strategy'].name))
    render_or_redirect
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: t('controllers.sessions.destroy')
  end

  protected

  def render_or_redirect
    page = env['omniauth.origin']
    if env['omniauth.params']['popup']
      @page = page
      render 'callback', layout: false
    else
      redirect_to page
    end
  end

  def pretty_name(provider_name)
    provider_name.titleize
  end
end
```

app/views/sessions/callback.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.opener.location = '<%= @page %>';
  window.close();
<% end %>
```